# Docker Maven Plugin hangs on start goal

Tags: java, maven, docker, integration-testing, fabric8

I want to create an application with IT tests for Oracle DB. So far I am stuck on building the docker (it is building but it never ends this goal)

POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle-connection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oracle-connection</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <docker.maven.plugin.version>0.27.2</docker.maven.plugin.version>
        <failsafe.plugin.version>2.22.1</failsafe.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.31.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-it-database</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <name>dbunit/dbunit-it-oracle11g:1.0.1</name>
                                    <alias>it-database</alias>
                                    <run>
                                        <ports>
                                            <port>1521:1521</port>
                                        </ports>
                                        <env>
                                            <ORACLE_PASSWORD>dbunit</ORACLE_PASSWORD>
                                            <ORACLE_DB>dbunit</ORACLE_DB>
                                        </env>
                                        <wait>
                                            <log>(?s)User altered.</log>
                                            <time>70000</time>
                                        </wait>
                                    </run>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>remove-it-database</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I do

```
mvn verify
```

and everything look until it hangs after building the docker (the start goal never ends)

```
<pre>
mvn clean verify -e docker:logs -Ddocker.follow -Ddocker.logDate=DEFAULT
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< pl.pgurdek:oracle-connection >--------------------
[INFO] Building oracle-connection 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\dev\oracle-connection\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\dev\oracle-connection\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\dev\oracle-connection\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\dev\oracle-connection\target\oracle-connection-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.31.0:start (prepare-it-database) @ oracle-connection ---
[INFO] DOCKER> [dbunit/dbunit-it-oracle11g:1.0.1] "it-database": Start container c405bf727b56
14:44:40.458 it-database> Starting Oracle Net Listener.
14:44:42.680 it-database> Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
14:44:55.335 it-database> 
14:44:56.041 it-database> 
14:44:56.041 it-database> System altered.
14:44:56.041 it-database> 
14:44:56.095 it-database> 
14:44:56.095 it-database> System altered.
14:44:56.095 it-database> 
14:44:56.121 it-database> Shutting down Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
14:45:25.765 it-database> Stopping Oracle Net Listener.
14:45:27.688 it-database> 
14:45:27.700 it-database> Starting Oracle Net Listener.
14:45:27.732 it-database> Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
14:45:35.643 it-database> 
14:45:35.649 it-database> /usr/sbin/startup.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
14:45:35.663 it-database> 
14:45:35.663 it-database> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jan 16 13:45:35 2020
14:45:35.663 it-database> 
14:45:35.663 it-database> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
14:45:35.663 it-database> 
14:45:35.697 it-database> 
14:45:35.697 it-database> Connected to:
14:45:35.697 it-database> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
14:45:35.697 it-database> 
14:45:35.747 it-database> 
14:45:35.747 it-database> User created.
14:45:35.747 it-database> 
14:45:35.759 it-database> 
14:45:35.759 it-database> Grant succeeded.
14:45:35.759 it-database> 
14:45:35.764 it-database> 
14:45:35.764 it-database> Grant succeeded.
14:45:35.764 it-database> 
14:45:35.769 it-database> 
14:45:35.769 it-database> Grant succeeded.
14:45:35.769 it-database> 
14:45:35.783 it-database> 
[INFO] DOCKER> Pattern '(?s)User altered.' matched for container c405bf727b56
14:45:35.783 it-database> User altered.
14:45:35.783 it-database> 
14:45:35.786 it-database> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
14:45:35.788 it-database> 
14:45:35.788 it-database> 
[INFO] DOCKER> [dbunit/dbunit-it-oracle11g:1.0.1] "it-database": Waited on log out '(?s)User altered.' 55487 ms

</pre>
```

I took an example from the link below. Which doesn't work neither.

https://github.com/fernandomoraes/medium-posts/tree/master/fail-safe-docker

Comment: What is your use case? If you don't want to start container, you can remove it from plugin `<executions>`

Comment: You can have a look at this example: https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/samples/custom-net/pom.xml#L25

Comment: My integration tests are not running after container is up. That' is my issue Rohan Kumar,